# Jquery Dialog single instance with disabled button works incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Am opening jquery dialog box and playing with dialog button per requirement like hiding 'save' after user click on it and doing more stuff after that per requirement and later on allow user to close it manually.

Am able to hide save button. Issue is when I open same dialog for other update requests (per requirement page shouldn't refresh after dialog close), I don't see 'save' button'.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

in html:

```
<div id="mydiv" title="my title">
</div>

    $('#mydiv).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 620,
        height: 550,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "Save": {
                id: "btnSave",
                text: "Save",
                click: function () {
                   // hide button

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you call `$('#mydiv').dialog({...})` again?

Comment: when I open same dialog for other requests, I do see it but 'save' button won't be seen.

Comment: Usually, when you run `$('#mydiv').dialog()` again, it should make another instance of the dialog (a newly constructed one). Please show how you're hiding the button.

Comment: $("#btnSave")[0].style.display = "none";

btnSave is button name in dialog

Comment: Try unhiding the button in the `open` event. `open: function(event, ui) { ... }`

Comment: well, I'm not keen to do that. Just wondering, why it doesn't show button again..

Comment: how are you showing the dialog? You could be reusing the one you've instantiated. If so, the elements inside the dialog are reused, not reconstructed. Try running `$('#mydiv').dialog({...})` again.